# gae xmpp and domains

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

i am using the gae xmpp service to send a chat message.

all simply enuff.

the message correctly sends to most domains, including tigase.im

however when the message is sent to a user on my own xmpp domain (mydomain.com) it returns with a  error.

hello

to complicate the issue, i have the same domain (mydomain.com) registered with google apps for business thingo, which hosts my email. it seems that as part of the package there is a chat service provided for the same domain.

i am guessing that appengine is ignoring the DNS record for mydomain.com and internally routing to the google apps for business domain thingo.

any help is most appreciate to confirm/deny or solve my problem.

-lp

Comment: Are you able to send a chat message from a non-App Engine account (eg. gmail) to an account on mydomain.com?

Do you need chat enabled for Google Apps accounts on the mydomain.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that Chat is *disabled* on your cpanel: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/mydomain.com/ServiceSettings#ServiceSettings/service=chat

Unlike email, where you can set MX records to point at different servers per account, XMPP can only redirect at the domain level. If Chat is enabled for Google Apps on your domain, all XMPP traffic for that domain will be handled by Google Apps.

Comment: yeap good answer.
i disabled the google chat and all is working.
still not clear why my SRV records were overridden by appengine.